# How to reduce server load without killing processes?

Tags: centos, unix, high-load

I am running a CentOS 6 VPS with WHM/cPanel. I am trying to move some accounts, to reduce load, so I have to run /scripts/pkgacct, however the gzip and other processes run by this script cause a very high load on my server. I would like to keep load low as possible while still being able to complete this process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set the nice and ionice value to a very high value. This won't lessen the load of the process but everything alse will always be prefered by the scheduler, resulting in a low performance loss.

Comment: If the command in question is already running, you can use `renice -p <PID> <PRIORITY>` and `ionice -c <CLASS> -p <PID>` to change their priorities.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use cPanel's build in load function? Just append this to your function:

`/usr/local/cpanel/bin/cpuwatch`

Example:

`/usr/local/cpanel/bin/cpuwatch 3 /scripts/pkgacct acctName`

This will run `/scripts/pkgacct acctName` and pause the process when the CPU load reaches above 3. The process will resume when the CPU load is below 3. Run `--help` on `cpuwatch` for full help menu.